# Laravel Eloquent Query Builder (with JOIN)

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

**Tables**

```
VENDOR
id    name    approved

PRODUCT
id    name    price    instock    fky_prod_vendor_id
```

**Relationship**

```
VENDOR(hasMany products()) <- (one-to-many) -> (hasOne vendor())PRODUCT
```

**Query**

How can I get all the **products** in-stock of a **approved vendor** using Eloquent given that the relationships are defined in Model?

My SQL is as following, but I need to use Eloquent relationship to achive the following.

```
select product.id
from   product, vendor
where  product.fky_prod_vendor_id = vendor.id
and    vendor.approved = 'y'
and    product.instock  > 0
```

Thanks

K

Comment: Everything you need to build this query is described in the laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries (about Where Clauses) and http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships (about Querying Relationship Existence

Answer (score 1):

As relationships are present, we can achieve this using Querying Relationship Existence method whereHas as rightly pointed out by @svrnm

```
PRODUCT::where('instock','>',0)
->whereHas('vendor', function ($query) { // Using Eloquent Query Existence, first parameter is name of relationship method, inside function is where clause on related model
            $query->where('approved','y');
        })->get();
```

That's magic of Laravel

Thanks

K